# How to have a backgroud image 100% width / height inside a <li>?

Tags: html, css

I have a slider with 4 items in it.

CSS

```
#section_3 {height:600px;}
#section_3 ul {list-style:none; width:400%; margin:0; padding:0;}
#section_3 ul li {float:left; width:25%; display:block; }
#section_3 ul li.sec1{background:url('../imgs/bg1.jpg') no-repeat; height:600px;}
#section_3 ul li.sec2{background:url('../imgs/bg2.jpg') no-repeat; height:600px;}
#section_3 ul li.sec3{background:url('../imgs/bg1.jpg') no-repeat; height:600px;}
#section_3 ul li.sec4{background:url('../imgs/bg2.jpg') no-repeat; height:600px;}
```

HTML

```
<div id="section_3" class="overflow">
        <ul id="slider">
            <li class="sec1">
                <h1>1</h1>
            </li>
            <li class="sec2">
                <h1>2</h1>
            </li>
            <li class="sec3">
                <h1>3</h1>
            </li>
            <li class="sec4">
                <h1>4</h1>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

The slider is working perfectly but now I would like to make in sort that each LI have it's own background 100% width and 100% height.

It could be in jQuery, javascript

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried using CSS background-size: 100% 100%;?

Comment: It must be cross-browser compatible :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't scale CSS background images in a cross-browser manner. You will need to put the image in the html (`<img/>`), absolute position it inside the `<li>` to take it out of the flow, and use CSS (possibly even JS depending on your situation)  to scale the image to 100% the size of the `<li>`.

Comment: Yeah seems to be the only way like this exemple: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-resizeable-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#section_3 ul li.sec1{background:url('../imgs/bg1.jpg') no-repeat; height:600px; background-size: 100% 100%;}
#section_3 ul li.sec2{background:url('../imgs/bg2.jpg') no-repeat; height:600px; background-size: 100% 100%;}
#section_3 ul li.sec3{background:url('../imgs/bg1.jpg') no-repeat; height:600px; background-size: 100% 100%;}
#section_3 ul li.sec4{background:url('../imgs/bg2.jpg') no-repeat; height:600px; background-size: 100% 100%;}
```

It's a simple fix in CSS. If you wanted to do it in Javascript, try

`document.getElementById("id_of_li").style.backgroundSize = "100% 100%";`

Check out the w3schools tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: This is CSS3 so not cross-browser compatible since must of users are still using IE8 and even IE7